# Unable to connect with mongodb localhost:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I trying to connect with mongodb using nodejs server and express. My mongoose version is 5.2.0 and mongodb version is 4.0. I have tried multiple ways to connect with mongodb but the mongod server just keeps listening and do not connect with the server and no database gets created. I have tried connecting with mongoose and also with mongoclient but mongod in cmd just keeps listening and do not get connected. here is my server code

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('./models/user');
var app = express();


var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/server", { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('There is error in connecting with mongodb');
    }
    console.log('Connection has been established.');
})
```

mongod in cmd

```
2019-01-13T23:56:05.690+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-13T23:56:05.691+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-01-13T23:56:05.691+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-01-13T23:56:05.692+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-01-13T23:56:05.692+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-01-13T23:56:05.693+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-01-13T23:56:05.693+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-01-13T23:56:05.694+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-13T23:56:06.073+0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2019-01-13T23:56:06.078+0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

mongo in cmd another window

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
Server has startup warnings:
2019-01-11T20:05:57.109+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-11T20:05:57.113+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-01-11T20:05:57.114+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-01-11T20:05:57.114+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
---

---
>
```

Comment: it is waiting for connection at 27017 after you run mongod, and then run your code. what is your out put ? can you `console.log(err)` and paste please

Comment: @feiiiiii no error not even any deprecated warning. just show in console that connection has been established. :/

Comment: What happens when you try connecting to it directly though command line with the `mongo` command?

Comment: @Ahsan then it means you are connected you should see console says so after waiting for connections on port 27017, then connect through command line with `mongo` . to see

Comment: @unflores yes i know and i did tried running mongo through another cmd window but still it was listening and there was no db created with name server :/

Comment: can anybody please tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `mongodb.bat` into the below-mentioned command:-

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "f:\mongodb\data"
```